# how to show a missing bootloader?

Tags: grub2, command-line, bootloader

I don't have a bootloader. there's just a GRUB terminal-like interface and apparently, linux terminal commands (e.g. exit, shutdown, poweroff) don't work on it so I don't know what to do with it.

I have windows 8 and ubuntu 12.04 (both 64bit) installed on the partitions of my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Boot using a live usb/cd of ubuntu. 
Use `boot-repair` to fix the problem.

After booting with live usb/cd ,Run following command in terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Use `Recomended Repair`

More information can be found here- > https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host")`

Comment: Please connect to internet first.

Comment: yes, actually I connected to the internet. I also changed necessary settings for proxy but it didn't work. 
so, I downloaded the iso file and burned it in CD but the boot repair disk tool simply closes after doing its thing.

Comment: Please boot on the Boot-Repair-Disk, open a terminal, type `sudo boot-repair -d`, press `Enter`, and indicate the output.